# Godep save deletes all deps in vendor and godep update

Tags: godeps

Im pretty new to Go but not to software. Im working on a new team with lots of projects and dependencies so we must use `godep`.

All the code is structure in the standard Go way, with files in `$GOPATH/.../github.com/...` etc (including our work which is in github)

I made changes to project A (`github.com/ourTeam/A`) and I want to run project B (`github.com/ourTeam/B`) which references A to test my code.
so I commit my work from A in my own branch in A, (and even pushed the branch).

-> **All I want is to update B with my new version of A.**

From B, I tried:

- `godep update github.com/A/subpackage`. It said 'godep: no packages can be updated'
- `godep save`. It deleted EVERYTHING in the vendor folder, leaving the `Godeps.json` file empty from any dependencies
- manually updating `Godeps.json` with my commit, then running godep update.
  No message but it didnt update anything. Godep save after this change deleted everything too in the vendor folder and Godep.json

What am I missing ?

Note: Im using godep v65 (darwin/amd64/go1.6.2) and `godep save -v` said

```
godep: Finding dependencies for [.]
godep: Found package: github.com/ourTeam/B
godep:  Deps:
(nothing so the diff with old file removes everything)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message when you tried to update tells me that the dependency on A had not been godep-saved before in B. That would mean you need to save it, instead of updating.

Today, I was having the same problem as you using `godep save`. All dependencies were being removed. However, this got me through it:

```
$ go get -u github.com/tools/godep # Make sure you have the latest godep (currently v71)
$ godep save ./... # Literally, "./..." is the argument

# The above command may fail with "Package not found ..."
# Install any package not found with "go get some/package/path"
$ go get some/package/path # if necessary
# Try "godep save ./..." again; repeat "go get" for any "not found" errors.
```

Once `godep save` returned without errors, I checked and it had done as expected. It only added the new dependency I had imported in the code.

Comment: Thanks, it was a bug in godep indeed, getting the latest version fixed it